# Is the word priorize acceptable?

Tags: etymology

Is the word priorize acceptable?  I used it and my son laughed at me and said the word is prioritize.

Comment: Your son is correct

Comment: Are you perchance converting an unused building into a priory?

Comment: When you ask a question like this, you should include what you found (or not) in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you meant "to make something prior"

> *Priorize that scene in the movie so the reveal is even more emotional.*

Pretty sure that's a Dr.Seuss word. You may have dropped the dental *(i)-t* from the conventional **[prioritize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prioritize)**, meaning to advance in necessity of attention (which is to make prior in a sense, I suppose...)

Comment: Apparently, [*priorizar*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/priorizar#Portuguese) is a Portuguese verb meaning "to prioritise (to give someone or something high priority)," several conjunctions of which are [*priorize*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/priorize). Then again, Portuguese isn't English . . .